# Access - query update with Inner Join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this query:

```
UPDATE client
SET client.[client_history] = 10
FROM  [T_CLIENT] AS client
     INNER JOIN (SELECT [client_id], SUM([final_price])
            FROM [T_PURCHASE]
            GROUP BY [client_id]) AS p
     ON client.[client_id] = p.[client_id]
```

When i execute this query on access, i get "Syntax Error".
Did you see something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You're not using the subquery that gets joined at all. If you share a more realistic attempt, I could show you how to replace a joined subquery with a domain aggregate

Comment: I shared a realist attempt.

Comment: Eh... Explain to me what that joined subquery is doing, then. You're not using any of it's fields, why is it there?

Comment: I wanna join all list of purchases of one client, after that, i wanna save the total amount in table client column, field client_history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `DSUM` to sum from a different table in an update query. Subqueries with aggregates won't work, because they're not updateable.

```
UPDATE t_client
SET [client_history] = DSUM("final_price", "T_PURCHASE", "client_id = " & client_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the syntax work without `FROM`:

```
UPDATE [T_CLIENT] AS client INNER JOIN
       (SELECT [client_id], SUM([final_price])
        FROM [T_PURCHASE]
        GROUP BY [client_id]
       ) AS p
      ON client.[client_id] = p.[client_id]
    SET client.[client_history] = 10;
```

Comment: Yes, and probably he want something like `SUM([final_price]) AS the_sum` and then `SET client.[client_history] = the_sum;`, i.e. the alias is required to be able the refer to the sum. Relying on column names given automatically by Access is dangerous, because they can differ in different language versions of Access.

Comment: That won't work, since the query won't be updatable. You can usually replace `INNER JOIN` and `SUM` with `DSUM`, but I'm a little unclear on the question since the joined subquery doesn't get used

Comment: Yes, i get an error: "Operation must use an updateable query"
Anyone knows?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929358/update-table-field-by-summing-field-from-another-table) has similar issue. It says `Operation must use an updateable query`. Can you please have a look.