# Update table field by summing field from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update a table filed taking value from another table by summing a field based on `EmpID`.

In `tblEmpInfo` `EmpID` is primary key. I have saw few post on this site but couldn't adopt to my file. Here is my code till yet.

```
UPDATE tblEmpInfo AS c 
INNER JOIN (SELECT EmpID, SUM(ProfidentFund) AS total FROM tblTransactions GROUP BY EmpID)  AS x ON c.EmpID = x.EmpID 
SET c.ProfidentFund = x.total;
```

Above code give me following warning and do not update value to `tblEmpInfo`

[image]

***`tblEmpInfo` screenshot***.

[image]

***`tblTransactions` screenshot.***

[image]

> ***And my expected output.***

[image]

Comment: Did you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789709/operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-error-in-ms-access

Comment: @ismetguzelgun I have tried `DISTINCTROW ` but no luck for me. Another thing is I am summing value of `ProfidentFund` field.

Comment: Your script seems legit. I do not understand why are you getting this error really. Summing is nothing unusual it should be okay.

Comment: [This post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62988053/access-update-with-subquery) solve my proble.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
UPDATE  c 
SET c.ProfidentFund = x.total
from tblEmpInfo AS c
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT EmpID, SUM(ProfidentFund) AS total FROM tblTransactions GROUP BY EmpID)  AS x 
    ON c.EmpID = x.EmpID
```

Comment: It gives me `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression...` prompt.