# ACCESS update with subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like this:
[image]

Now I'm trying to write in the column "SUMAMOUNT" of the table the sum of amount per "CODE" and "IBAN" but i can't reach this.

I'd want something like this:

[image]

I'm using this query but it doesn't work:

```
update tabella
set sumamount = (select sum(t2.amount)
                  from tabella as t2
                  where t2.code = tabella.code and t2.iban = tabella.iban
                 );
```

The precedent query gives me this result:



[image]


Can you help me? I'm using MS ACCESS.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Screenshot of the error:

[image]

I can't even try to run it because he ask me to save it. When I try to save, access gives me this error.

Answer (score 2):

Consider domain aggregate, `DSum`, which allows an updateable query. Below assumes `code` and `iban` are text types and therefore requires single quote enclosures.

```
UPDATE tabella t
SET t.sumamount = DSUM("amount", 
                       "tabella",  
                       "code = '" & t.code & "' AND iban = '" & t.iban & '");
```

(By the way, best practice in databases is to avoid saving calculations in tables. Save resources and simply run queries on data as needed.)

Comment: Is `DSUM` only available within Access (like `Nz()`) - or does it work when using ODBC/OLEDB from other applications too?

Comment: Fantastic! Upvote for excellent solution. I had same issue and this answer solved my problem. Again, many thanks.

Comment: @Dai, domain aggregates are available as part of Access' dialect in ODBC/OLEDB connections.